# Test breadcrumb directive that uses $location service

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I'm trying to write a simple unit test for a breadcrumb directive/service. Basically, all I want to do is to change the location.path (or whatever the right way to do this is) and then be able to run expects on the directive's HTML, to see that the breadcrumb list has updated.

The breadcrumb service (borrowed from [AngularJS Breadcrumbs Service](https://gist.github.com/benschw/5516156)) looks like this:

```
var commonModule = angular.module('app.common');

commonModule.factory('common.service.breadcrumbs', ['$rootScope', '$location', function($rootScope, $location){

    var breadcrumbs = [];
    var breadcrumbsService = {};

    function setBreadcrumbs() {
        var pathElements = $location.path().split('/'), result = [], i;
        var breadcrumbPath = function (index) {
            return '/' + (pathElements.slice(0, index + 1)).join('/');
        };

        pathElements.shift();
        for (i=0; i<pathElements.length; i++) {
            result.push({name: pathElements[i], path: breadcrumbPath(i)});
        }

        breadcrumbs = result;
    }

    setBreadcrumbs();

    // We want to update breadcrumbs only when a route is actually changed
    // $location.path() will get updated immediately (even if route change fails!)
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function(event, current){
        setBreadcrumbs();
    });

    breadcrumbsService.getAll = function() {
        return breadcrumbs;
    };

    breadcrumbsService.getFirst = function() {
        return breadcrumbs[0] || {};
    };

    return breadcrumbsService;
}]);
```

And my current test looks like this:

```
describe("Directive:", function() {

    beforeEach(angular.mock.module("app"));

    var $compile,
        $scope,
        $location;

    // Angular strips the underscores when injecting
    beforeEach(inject(function(_$compile_, _$rootScope_, _$location_) {
        $compile = _$compile_;
        $scope = _$rootScope_.$new();
        $location = _$location_;
    }));

    describe("breadcrumbs", function () {

        it("correctly display the path as breadcrumbs.",
            inject(['common.service.breadcrumbs', function(breadcrumbs) {

                //console.log($location.path());
                //$scope.$apply();
                $location.path('/analyze/reports');
                $scope.$apply();
                //console.log($location.path());
                //console.log(breadcrumbs.getAll());

                $scope.$broadcast('$routeChangeSuccess', {});

                // Build the directive
                var element = $compile('<div class="cf-breadcrumbs" cf-breadcrumbs></div>')($scope);
                $scope.$apply();

                console.log(element.html());
            }]));

    });

});
```

currently, I'm not ever seeing the breadcrumb service update the array of breadcrumbs. I've tried console.log(breadcrumbs.getAll()), and it always returns the same array without the two new path elements. I'm concerned that it might be something timing related, but not exactly sure how I would wait for the $routeChangeSuccess event to affect the service before I do my check/apply.

Long story short, how would I test to see that the breadcrumbs are updated appropriately?

Comment: $broadcast from $rootScope in your test. $scope is a child scope of $rootScope, so an event broadcasted from that will not go upwards where you've attached the $on handler.

Comment: @user2943490 I can't believe that after everything I tried I did not think of that. Works like a charm. If you write it as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$broadcast from $rootScope in your test. $scope is a child scope of $rootScope as it was created with `$rootScope.$new()`, so an event broadcasted from that will not go upwards where you've attached the $on handler.

$broadcasts travel downwards to child scopes, while $emits travel upwards.